# interpret communication from / dev files

Tags: linux, device, hardware

I want to intercept the content emitted by the keyboard,

I know that each device has a file linked to it,

my question is how to intercept a 'specific' usb port and where to find the documentation to interpret the data

Sorry for the english (google translator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on: https://sergioprado.org/implementando-um-teclado-virtual-no-linux/

The file that abstracts event capture from input devices like mouse, keyboard, joysticks, touch screens, etc. is `/ dev / input`

You can use an "evtest" tool to check which device is related to a given file: example `evtest / dev / input / event4`

---

**Português**

Baseado em: https://sergioprado.org/implementando-um-teclado-virtual-no-linux/

O arquivo que  abstrai a captura de eventos de dispositivos de entrada como mouse, teclado, joysticks, touch screens, etc é `/dev/input`

Você pode usar a ferramenta "evtest" para verificar qual o dispositivo relacionado à determinado arquivo: exemplo `evtest /dev/input/event4`

Comment: https://thehackerdiary.wordpress.com/2017/04/21/exploring-devinput-1/

link relevante a interpretação